# Сделать кликабельным динамический объект в С#

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть прямоугольник который можно передвигать. Необходимо что бы при нажатии на него открывалось окно. Пробовал сделать так, но не работает.

```
private void rect1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("lol");
}
```

Comment: что за _rect1_? И где используешь этот обработчик?

Comment: @Grundy, да не использует он его. Просто написал и всё. И хва закрывать всё подряд.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не надо наговаривать, этот вопрос я еще не закрывал :)

Comment: Сказал @Grundy и добавил второй голос :D

Comment: @Qwertiy, это все еще был не я:)

Comment: я полагаю не нужно пояснять, что `rect1` кроме всего прочего должен являться контролом, т.е. наследоваться от `Control` или его производных. Обычный класс вроде `System.Drawing.Rectangle` не подойдет.

Answer (score 0):

На событие (если оно вообще существует) сначала надо подписаться. Возможно так:

```
rect1.Click += rect1_Click;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я попробую.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы динамически созданный объект мог реагировать на клик мышки, необходимо задать метод, который будет вызываться при инициировании события.
Например:

```
obj.Click += obj_Click;
```

В вашем случае это необходимо сделать для объекта `rect1`

**Важно заметить**, что не всякий метод можно присоединить к цепочке делегатов: метод должен принимать следующие параметры `object` и `EventArgs`

Так же можно присоединить метод следующим образом, используя лямбда выражения

```
obj.Click += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show("obj click!");
```

Comment: @ИльяДанилов если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).